# How to communicate between AngularDart 4.0 components

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

in main.dart

```
bootstrap(FooComponent);
bootstrap(BarComponent);
```

in component.dart file

```
class FooComponent {
  String content = "abc";
  void changeBarContent(){
    // change bar content here
  }
}

class BarComponent {
  String content = "efg";
}
```

First,I want set content in main.dart like FooComponent.content="hi from main".

Second,I want set BarComponent's content from FooComponent.

How to do those?

Comment: If you want to communicate between two top angular apps (that is what you have with each bootstrap) I'd consolidate the apps using a wrapper. Angular assumes bootstrap'd apps are largely independent. You can communicate using window variables, but nothing in angular itself.

Comment: As with communicating with a top level App bootstrap returns a ComponentRef which has an instance field that you can use to access the particular component. There you could set data on the component, but I think you are going to be working outside of change detection so you would have to use ChangeDetectorRef to tell angular things have changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you compile this as a single project then you can share any global objects visible to the libraries.

It can be as simple as a variable in a library that both Apps/components access, but if you want something more testable you should create a class, and inject it inside your components' constructors, and provide the same instance to both in the bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a simple singleton service that is injected into both components.  Your FooComponent could update a value in that service via the changeBarContent method, and the BarComponent could reference the service's value.  If the value you're attempting to update is a primitive, you would need to create a wrapper object around it.

I'm new to AngularDart, so I can't say that's a best practice, but it is a possible way to handle what you're looking to do.